# Should I update lists in place with React?

Tags: reactjs

To delete an item from a list, I created a new list that does not contain the deleted item, and replaced the old list with the new. Is this the "right" way or should I edit the list in place? I suspect this may be inefficient for JS.

```jsx
destroy: function(chosenItem) {
  var newItems = this.state.items.filter(function(item) {
    return chosenItem.id != item.id;
  });
  this.setState({items:newItems});
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of things:

1. if such items have any sort of persistence mechanism attached, consider using any action architecture [see [Flux](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/flux-overview.html), [Reflux](https://github.com/spoike/refluxjs)...], so that you do not set the state of your component directly, but you delegate deletion to a separate entity, that will later on notify your component of the update;
2. creators of React evangelise about [immutable objects](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/) in order to work w/ React, so your choice is definitely fine.

Comment: I now "get" immutable.js. For example, to update a todo in a list 1) the update callback passes in edited todo 2) new todo list is created by splicing in the edited todo 3) setState with new todo list. Its easy to pass stuff around when you dont worry about functions editing it.

Comment: @aitchnyu you got it : ))